# Change RelayState in AD FS

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, adfs, adfs2.1

Consider following situation: We're currently in a migration phase where the majority of our users should still be forwarded to the existing application A. Other users that fulfil some certain criteria (let's call them beta-testers) should instead be forwarded to the new application B.

Users reach our AD FS with a POST request that contains the SAMLResponse and the RelayState. The RelayState-parameter tells our AD FS the desired target-application. Up to now it always contains "site A" since the users don't know about site B yet ;-)

I'm wondering if there's a way to dynamically change the process our ADFS determines the target application based on the value of the RelayState-parameter?
So what I'm looking for is a way to somehow **modify the RelayState based on a certain claim** the user provides. E.g. if the user has a "beta-tester" entry in her role-claim, then our ADFS should forward her to site B instead of site A.

Is there a way to hook into the AD FS procssing pipeline? The only thing I found so far is [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn783423.aspx) describing how to "inject" a custom authentication method. But that's obvisiously not what I'm looking for.

So could anybody tell me if there are any other extension points I could utilize to achieve what I described above?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no - there is no way to dynamically change RelayState.

ADFS is locked down (as it is a security system) and doesn't have extension points.

Could you have two RP during the transition?

Comment: Thank you for your response! Having two RPs seems like an obvious solution. Unfortunately this requires the IdP to provide two links to our applications. And that's what I'd like to avoid.

Comment: You have to have two RP anyway for ADFS to distinguish. Just give the "B" group the new URL and they can manually navigate to it.

Comment: Sorry, I got that wrong. Of course there will be two RPs configured. One for site A and one for site B. But when die SAMLResponse arrives, ADFS should choose on its own whether to forward the user to A or B. Ideally the user shouldn't see ADFS's dropdown box for manually chosing the RP.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to setup a proxy site where you can apply custom logic as necessary for scenarios like this.  My experience is there are numerous times when it's handy to have a point of entry into the federation process, i.e. a psuedo-extension point, where you can apply custom logic.  So, everyone from the IdP may go to https://proxy.mysite.com and then that site would make determinations based on claims and maybe querystring, posted variables or header attributes, as to where to send (redirect) the user to next, https://a.mysite.com or https://b.mysite.com.

DNS can also be folded in, to do things like direct https://a.mysite.com to the proxy site and the proxy site can then look at the hostname of the request and know that the user intended to go to a.mysite.com, but you can determine if a beta tester and direct to b.mysite.com or the actual A site.

Comment: Yep, this would be a way that came to our minds, too. The main downside is that this proxy has to be set up itself in the first place. Meaning it has to be developed and it has to be hosted as another high-available application. So this somehow seems like the way to go, but it seems like a toilsome way.

Comment: It certainly does add another possible point of failure and site to manage.  If you do come up with another method, I would be interested to know what you found.